# How to exclude a folder from rsync

Tags: rsync

I am trying to backup my home folder on my NAS drive. I am giving this:

```
rsync -Paz --exclude-from 'rsync-exclude.txt' /home/chris/ admin@192.168.1.65:LinuxHome
```

where `rsync-exclude.txt` has this content:

```
/home/chris/Downloads/*
/home/chris/Downloads/
/home/chris/Downloads/*.*
```

and it is in the same folder I execute rsync (home folder).

However the rsync tries to copy this folder, too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You are providing *absolute* paths in your exclude list.

With rsync, all exclude (or include!) paths beginning with `/` are anchored to the "*root of transfer*".

The root of transfer in this case is `/home/chris`. If you did:

```
rsync -Paz --exclude-from 'rsync-exclude.txt' / admin@192.168.1.65:`
```

…then your exclusions should work (but you'd be copying *everything else* on that filesystem!).

But since you're just trying to sync your *home* directory, and there is no subdirectory of `/home/chris` named `"home/chris/Downloads"`, `rsync` finds nothing that matches.

So try removing the `/home/chris` parts from your `rsync-exclude.txt` file.

Actually, you should just need a single line in the file:

```
/Downloads
```

**Note** that if you don't specify the leading `/`, and you happen to have other directories named `"Downloads"`, those would also be excluded. I'm assuming you only want to exclude your "top-level" (relative to the source directory, aka the "root of transfer") `Downloads` directory, so you'll want the leading `/`.

#### The easiest way (to exclude only a few paths)

If you only need to exclude one directory, just do this (avoiding a separate file):

```
rsync -Paz --exclude /Downloads /home/chris/ admin@192.168.1.65:LinuxHome
```

You can also chain together `--exclude` tags, like so:

```
rsync -Paz --exclude /Downloads --exclude '/Pictures' --exclude .cache \
  /home/chris/ admin@192.168.1.65:LinuxHome
```

Note that in this example, since `.cache` has no leading slash, rsync will exclude any file *or directory* named `.cache` from *every* directory it transfers. You can leave out the backslash (\), as long as you type everything on a single line. It has nothing to do with rsync.

If you have more than a few exclusions, you're better off with `--exclude-from` and a file.

#### Note

I see that you got it right, but those new to rsync should **note the slash at the end** of `/home/chris/`

To quote the `rsync` man page, "You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning 'copy the contents of this directory' as opposed to 'copy the directory by name'."

So if you left off that trailing slash, you would end up with a directory called `chris` within the target directory, *containing* everything from `/home/chris` (except the original `Downloads` directory, of course!).

Comment: Aah, at least a fine and definitive answer about excluding absolute paths, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This might be easier on the eyes, and just a note on excluding directories and syntax:

```
SRC='/home/username'
DST='/run/media/username/EasyStoreRT/rsync'

rsync -avrh --stats                                 \
    --log-file=/home/username/log/rsync-home.log    \
    --exclude='/username/.cache'                    \
    --exclude='/username/.local/share/Trash'        \
    $SRC \
    $DST \
```

It will exclude those directories and all files within them.  For whatever reason, rysnc wasn't appending /home/username to /.cache. Only home/ would anchor itself, so I had to add /username to each excluded directory.

The man pages say, "if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname." But, that hierarchy seems to only be the first directory in the source directory.  I'm using bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release.